# Add Images to google MAP

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a website contains google map.I need to pin images to a particular place in the map.
Is possible to add programetically this images to the Map.
For example, if my data base contains image location and the details of place want to add.I need to add all images from my database to the corresponding placed in the map.

If possible which google API i can use for this purpose.My developing environment is LAMP.

Thanks,
Companion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They're called info windows and are attached to markers. The Google Maps API reference is very detailed and full of samples with code.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows

Your PHP code will output (echo) JavaScript to add the appropriate markers to your map.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean [a ground overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GroundOverlay)?